# Removing Title Bar on Android App

Tags: java, android, xml

So I know there are a ton of these questions, but every time I try what they say, my app does not seem to remove the title bar. I have done the style change:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>   <!-- This should work but it does not -->
</style>
```

I have also tried:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide(); //This guy here
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_title);
```

The above works but I still want to use the space the title bar takes for content in my app, which is why I want to be able to modify the XML code rather than use java. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a theme that does not include the ActionBar. Your AppTheme has a parent that extends DarkActionBar.

Comment: And for the record: Setting android:windowNoTitle removes the title. But it doesn't remove the actionbar if you have something else on it. A menu for an instance

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

```
<style name="noActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and in your layout(at the root layout)

```
android:theme="@theme/noActionBar"
```

Or

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

However, the last one also hides the Statusbar. You can also set the theme to a default theme(look through the themes and find those with NoActionBar). The last one is useful if you have no plans to style the activity(for an instance if you use SurfaceView) with custom colors, etc.

For an instance you can change AppBaseTheme to have the parent `Holo.Light.NoActionBar` or any similar theme, but the name has to contain NoActionBar, othervise it has an actionbar

Answer (score 0):

Add the below theme to `style.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Then set this theme to your Activity in `manifest`:

```
<activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```